# Swift's web view is only printing <head></head><body></body> as innerhtml

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode, webview

I was trying to followings [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gscuaUSkxnI) on using webview,  but when I wrote this code:

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML",
                                       completionHandler: {(value, error) in
                                        print("INNER HTML: \(value!)")
                                        print("ERROR \(String(describing: error))")
```

all I get in the console is `<head></head><body></body>` when it should be printing gmail's inner html. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Also, from this code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.gmail.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300)
        webView.load(request)
        view.addSubview(webView)
```

I should have a view of the login page, but I don't get anything on the simulator (not very important,  but would be helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned WkWebView from the exact same tutorial!  Go Kilo Loco!

My code ended up a little different, after I did a lot of Stack Overflow searches. 
 This code prints the HTML in the completion handler, and saves the HTML to a var called webString I defined in my ViewController:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript(
  "document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
    completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
        print("error: '\(String(describing: error))'")
        self.webString = html as! String
//  print("webString: '\(self.webString)'")
    })
```

Also, remember to add the WKNavigationDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
```

And, For macOS app, enable incoming and outgoing Network access in your app's Capabilities tab.  If you forget this step, you won't see anything in your WkWebView:

[image]

Here is my working iOS View Controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var currentHTML: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.gmail.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

//        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300)
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    // WKNavigationDelegate method
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(
            "document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
            completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                self.currentHTML = html as! String
                print("In compHandler, HTML: \(self.currentHTML.count) bytes\n")
        })

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(
            "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML",
            completionHandler: {(value, error) in
                print("INNER HTML: \(value!)")
                print("ERROR \(String(describing: error))")
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I can't seem to find enable incoming and outgoing network access, can you tell me the exact name?

Comment: This still prints <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: I've added an image with directions to clarify how to enable incoming and outgoing Network in the Capabilites tab.  Remember to re-enable Sandbox after making these changes..  This should help!

Comment: I did some researching and I think the reason I do not have the App Sandbox capabilities is because I am building an iOS app while you are building a macOS app. I think for iOS we do not need to enable it since Kilo Loco did not do it either, but his app worked perfectly fine

Comment: You are correct.  I was looking at one of my macOS apps for this image.  My apologies. The evaluateJavaScript() code works on both platforms.

Comment: Are you still having issues? I was able to get your code working in a new app.  The only change I made was to the CGRect code.  Let me know if you want me to copy/paste my working ViewController.  I see the entire Gmail HTML printed to the debug display.

Comment: Yes, I am still having issues, a copy and paste would be very nice

Comment: OK. I've added my view controller code.  Note that I kept my Java script code along with yours.  You can run multiple Java script from the delegate method.  Hope this solves it for you!

Comment: I changed y: 60 to y: 0 in the CGRect line.  I was using y: 60 in my mac app to push the WebView down enough for a row of buttons.  For a full screen iOS app, y: 0 is correct.

Comment: A few questions: do you have a WebView of gmail on your app? because I do not have anything -- just a blank screen that fills up the app. Was this made on a single view app with out any UI elements? When is the function called?

Comment: Yes, I can see the Gmail login page in the simulator.  Yes, it is a single view app. I did not add any UI elements in Interface Builder (IB).  This code creates the WKWebView programatically. If you have a WebView in IB, delete it. A simple test for you would be to create a new single view iOS app, and copy/paste this code to the new app's view controller, then run it.  That should work. Let me know what you see...

Comment: I see nothing in the console or on the app. Just to be lear, you did nothing else to the app other than make a single view application, copy and past my code, and edit it right?

Comment: Correct.  No changes other than the ViewController code I pasted above.  Did you create a new single view iOS app, and try this code? Quit out of Xcode, restart your mac, and create a new app.  If that doesn't work, then you have some issues with your environment or your copy of Xcode itself.

Comment: It's still not working, as a last attempt, what's your Xcode version?

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.2.1 under Mojave 10.14.5.  This app works for me.  I originally ran Kilo Loco's code under Xcode 9.4.1 and High Sierra, so I know it works under older versions as well. Sorry this isn't working for you.  I know how frustrating that is...

Comment: You are absolutely right. After spending a lot of time trying to figure out the problem, I found out that it was because of an antivirus that blocked all sites on the simulator. If I run the code on a physical device, it works. Thanks for sticking around to try to help!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved!  What antivirus software are you using?  I am really surprised that any antivirus software would interfere with the Xcode simulator.  I'm glad I was able to help, even if it was only to let you know what code should work! If my answer helped, please mark it as correct, or add your own answer to indicate the issue was the AV software.

Comment: It wasn't superimposed by me, but by apple in safari (I know this because I didn't install any antivirus yet.) I think it was called AVG, but I'm not sure. Maybe I meddled with some settings a long time ago and it caused this